# WP Cron: wp_get_schedule( $hook ) returns nothing

Tags: wp-cron

I have the following action:

```
add_action( 'wi_schedule_sync', array($this, 'schedule_sync') );
```

I'm trying to confirm that it is being registered, by calling this function --

```
wp_get_schedule( 'wi_schedule_sync' );
```

-- but I am always getting nothing.

Why is this?

Comment: What is `wi_schedule_sync`? ([not an official hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=wi_schedule_sync)) Please name the plugin you are using and you'll probably get even better help in their support forum

Comment: This is a custom hook we have defined. Does it matter whether it is an official hook?

The point is that it should have been scheduled but wp_get_schedule() does not return it.

Comment: The point is, with the code you posted we have no idea how you schedule the event, so we can't tell you at all why it is not scheduled

Comment: Have you scheduled the hook? You need to call `wp_schedule_event()` to schedule `wi_schedule_sync`.